# Why do job ads use the word "discipline" to mean different areas/types of jobs?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, meaning-in-context

I find on some companies' websites that they use the word "**disciplines**" to mean different areas/types of jobs.

One of their job descriptions says "You will work across the company with other product groups, as well as across the aisle with other **disciplines**."

I look up the word *discipline* and the closest meaning I think is "a field of study" from [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/discipline) or "an area of knowledge or teaching that is studied at a university" from [Longman](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/discipline). I can't find the meaning related to different types of jobs.

So why do they use it and why is there a separate *profession* section from the *discipline* section?

Cambridge dictionary (As Jim pointed out) uses a sentence "Our company actively recruits graduates for a wide range of **disciplines** including engineering, science, and business." But **recruiting new graduate** and **recruiting professionals** is different. If it is recruiting new graduate it is easy to understand the meaning of discipline as "an area of knowledge or teaching that is studied at a university" from Longman.

But the picture I attached is recruiting professionals so using discipline there is bit confusing to me.

> [image: discipline header. Options are: software engineering, program management, product design, product management, product marketing, technical program management]

Comment: Hello, Qiulang 邱朗. No, I can't find this sense in any of the usual respectable free online dictionaries; perhaps OED picks up on it now. It's a broadened usage, from 'specific area of studies/knowledge' to 'specific area of expertise', ie 'specialism'.

Comment: [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/discipline) has: **a subject or a particular type of work:**  *Our company actively recruits graduates for a wide range of disciplines including engineering, science, and business.*

Comment: @Jim Getting old; missed that. Worth an 'answer': this isn't easily available from a single source.

Comment: [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/discipline) has "If you refer to an activity or situation as a discipline, you mean that, in order to be successful in it, you need to behave in a strictly controlled way and obey particular rules or standards." This seems something that companies would believe about working in different areas, even if the impartial observer might be skeptical about how controlled and ordered they really are.

Comment: Updated my question. They separate professions section from discipline section, which I also feel confused. But after reading all the answers and comments I begin to understand.

Comment: The full OED has definition 7a *A branch of learning **or knowledge**; a field of study **or expertise**; a subject. Now also: a **subcategory or element** of a particular subject or **field.*** Citations include (1962, Lancet 13 Jan) *Sir Leonard Parsons..had been the first to draw into the paediatrics of his time **other disciplines such as biochemistry and immunology.*** I'd say those are references to *working professional areas of expertise* rather than just "academic" subject divisions.

Comment: I don't understand why my question is closed. I did do my research, checking discipline from different dictionaries. Without the answers/comments I got I had hard time to understand it.

Answer (score 8):

I believe the actual job titles would be in the "Role Type" section and "Discipline" in the example refers to fields (and subfields) of study.

> "You will work across the company with other product groups, as well
> as across the aisle with other disciplines."

For example if your job is in the discipline of *graphic design* (e.g., you are *commercial artist*), you might have to work with a packaging engineer who works in the discipline of *packaging design*. Sometimes the name of a discipline and a job title may be quite similar, such as *software/packing engineer(ing)* and *graphic design(er)*.

**Discipline** (n.)

> A branch of learning or knowledge; a field of study or expertise; a
> subject. **Now also: a subcategory or element of a particular subject
> or field.**
>
> **1962**   *Lancet* 13 Jan. 113/1   Sir Leonard Parsons..had been the first to draw into the paediatrics of his time other **disciplines**
> such as biochemistry and immunology.
>
> **1999**   *Independent* (Nexis) 16 Apr. 22   Becky, regarded as the brightest prospect in British gymnastics started her sport at five...
> Her favourite (and best) **discipline** is the asymmetric bars.
>
> **2007**   *N.Y. Times* (National ed.) 28 Jan. viii. 1/2   Duncan is a founder of the World Power Sports Association, which runs a national
> race series for snowmobile snocross, a **discipline** similar to
> motocross. (OED online)

---

> The boundaries of what were once recognised as discrete design
> **disciplines** such as product, graphic, textile, and fashion design have been and continue to dissolve... [P. Rodgers and C. Bremmer;
> *Design School*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Design_School_After_Boundaries_and_Disci/nt2GDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=product%20design%20is%20a%20discipline&pg=PA174&printsec=frontcover) (2019)

> Product design engineering whilst a relatively new engineering
> **discipline**, is gaining support with global distribution of curricula. These pioneering curricula integrate the traditionally
> disparate **disciplines** of industrial design and mechanical
> engineering to develop a creative 'next generation' engineering more
> adapt at the changing roles of product design and development. [A.
> Silva and R. Simões; *Handbook of Research on Trends in Product Design
> and Development*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Handbook_of_Research_on_Trends_in_Produc/PZZ9UMNWkn0C?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=product%20design%20is%20a%20discipline&pg=PA184&printsec=frontcover) (2010)

Comment: WordReference Random House Learner's Dictionary of American English © 2022 -- https://www.wordreference.com/definition/discipline
**discipline** n. 6. a branch of instruction or learning:
[countable] "the disciplines of history and economics."

Comment: @Greybeard I thought the OP was asking about  divisions finer than branches/fields of study like history and economics.

Comment: Yes, I realised that, but you mentioned not being able to find a definition for the finer details and or within a profession and *"a branch of instruction or learning"* is vague enough to cover that.

Comment: @Greybeard I believe that was Edwin. But I agree with you, I have no difficulty understanding *discipline* as a finer division.

Comment: @DjinTonic thanks for answering my question. I updated my question to show what it is in role type.

Comment: They separate profession section from discipline section, which I also find confused.

Comment: It may be; however, if these are checkboxes, you can broaden/narrow you search. With a bit of trial and error, you should be able which (sub)categories the jobs of interest are in.

Answer (score 3):

[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/discipline) gives:

> **a subject or a particular type of work**:
> *Our company actively recruits graduates for a wide range of disciplines including engineering, science, and business.*

Comment: But it is easy to understand the disciplines in "recruits graduates for a wide range of disciplines" as ""an area of knowledge or teaching that is studied at a university"

Comment: Yes, that’s why Cambridge chose that for its example.

Comment: What I mean was recruiting new graduate and recruiting professionals is different. While the picture I attached is  recruiting professionals so using disciplines there is bit confusing. If it is recruiting new graduate as that sentence you quoted, it is easy to understand.

Comment: Not that the example says ***”for*** a wide range of disciplines” not ***”with*** a wide range” This is because they are hiring for the disciplines they need within the company- the particular types of work they do and need.

Comment: Oh thanks. As a non-native speaker I saw that but I didn't realize that was the key difference!

Answer (score 1):

OED defines ***discipline*** as *a **subcategory** or **element** of a particular subject or field* (also mentioned in DjinTonic's answer). So the examples in the image you have posted are each a subcategory of a broader discipline/field of study (such as engineering, design, etc.).

Hence, "Software Engineering" is a discipline of Engineering:

> Software engineering is an engineering discipline that's applied to the development of software in a systematic approach (called a software process).
>
> (From [medium.com](https://medium.com/omarelgabrys-blog/software-engineering-introduction-part-1-b79238ec97ee#:%7E:text=Software%20engineering%20is%20an%20engineering,%2Deffectively%2C%20and%20ensures%20quality.))

"Product Design" is a discipline of Design:

> Product Design is a design discipline that focuses on developing solutions to human needs, wants, limitation and desires.
>
> (From [designcarlow](https://designcarlow.ie/what-is-design.html))

"Product Marketing" is a discipline of Marketing:

> Product marketing is a marketing discipline that focuses on the process of bringing a specific product to the marketplace.
>
> (From [directiveconsulting.com](https://designcarlow.ie/what-is-design.html))

"Product Management" is a discipline of Management:

> Management as a discipline refers to that branch of knowledge which is connected to study of principles & practices of basic administration.
>
> (From [managementstudyguide.com](https://www.managementstudyguide.com/management_discipline.htm#:%7E:text=Management%20as%20a%20discipline%20refers,methods%20for%20managing%20resources%20efficiently.))

Marketing and Management are themselves disciplines of [Business](https://yourbusiness.azcentral.com/business-disciplines-8106.html).

Comment: Updated my question. They separate professions section from discipline section, which I also feel confused. After reading all the answers and comments although it makes sense now but I still feel they do it to make their job ads looks more "fancy"

Answer (score 1):

All three of the answers so far and a number of the comments have been helpful.  Nevertheless. It may be worth getting briefly into the etymology of it.

The Latin 'disciplina' is formed from from the verb *disco*, meaning *I learn*.  Someone who learns from a teacher, a pupil, was called *discipulus*;  what a discipulus learns can be called a *disciplina*.  Before well into the twentieth century, the teaching of boys could be a brutal business.  The great Roman Poet, Horace, refers to his teacher as "plagosus Orbilius ", immortalised by his brilliant pupil for his cruel teaching methods.  Schooling and corporal punishment became disturbingly associated together and corporal punishment was not mage illegal in the U.K. schools until 1986.  So it is not surprising that the word *discipline* should have given its name both to the knowledge and skills learned but to the brutal methods employed in imparting them.

At universities, the academic meaning of the knowledge, understanding and skills acquired and exercised continues because that is what their profession does.  Even here, however, the use of the word *discipline*, compared to, say, *subject*, gives it an edge of rigour/self-control, coming from that other sense of 'discipline' associated with control by punishment.

For that reason it is not uncommon for secondary schools with aspirations to academic prestige to refer to subjects as *disciplines*

For that reason also, it is not surprising that some companies choose to refer to different departments as *disciplines*, combining as they do expertise/knowhow with seriousness and self control not inflicted by the brutal Whacker Orbilius.

Comment: For all the answers, I learn most from your words "it is not surprising that some companies choose to refer to different departments as disciplines, combining as they do expertise/knowhow with seriousness and self control".

Comment: @Qiulang邱朗 Glad to be of help.